How to use sticky element in a scroll table
I want to implement a scroll table with a fix column in the left side. But there is a problem which is that the fix DOM can't be fixed.
Just like the pictures show in
image 1 and
image 2.
How do I fix the red text in left side when scrolling to the right. The table also can scroll up and down.
Here is my code


<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .wrapper{
            width: 400px;
            height: 100px;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
        .container {
            width: 1000px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            height: 150px;
        }

        .list {
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 1000px;
        }

        .list span {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
        }

        .fix {
            position: sticky;
            left: 0px;
            background: red;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>




What is your expectation result looks like @user20279345

This question is similar to: How do I create an HTML table with a fixed/frozen left column and a scrollable body?. In particular, look at this answer which matches your scenario pretty closely.

Just adjust something like this, your problem is use overflow for .wrapper and wrong overflow attribute for .container class.


<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 400px;
            overflow:auto;
            height: 150px;
        }

        .list {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .list span {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
        }

        .fix {
            position: sticky;
            left: 0px;
            background: red;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list">
                <span class="fix">TEXT 1</span>
                <span>TEXT 2</span>
                <span>TEXT 3</span>
                <span>TEXT 4</span>
                <span>TEXT 5</span>
                <span>TEXT 6</span>
                <span>TEXT 7</span>
                <span>TEXT 8</span>
                <span>TEXT 9</span>
                <span>TEXT 10</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>



